# Swift create cocoapod with dependency error

Tags: ios, swift, dependencies, cocoapods

Trying my hand at building a cocoapod and I need to include the SwiftKeyChainWrapper cocoapod as a dependency. I have the pod linked inside the .podSpec file but (1) I can't find a way to include it in the development pod whilst I build it to use methods and (2) when I run `pod lib lint --verbose --no-clean --use-libraries` I get the following error:

> - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The Swift Pods being used are: SwiftKeychainWrapper

Inside the pod project I have the following:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'MyPod_Example' do   
  pod 'MyPod', :path => '../'

  target 'MyPod_Tests' do
  inherit! :search_paths


  end
end
```

And the dependency is listed:

```
s.dependency 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`--use-libraries` is the flag to use static libraries instead of  dynamic frameworks, you should remove it from your lint command to make it work as a framework.